# Regex Always False multi Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am facing a weird issue with Regex. My expression working fine in https://regexr.com/3cr6f
But when i use the same expression in my code then it start failing.

This is my Expression:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\\)+(Documents){1}\\{1}((CT([A-Za-z]){0,2})|(FE)|(FF))$
```

I want to test this expression on my typescript string:

```
 var case1='User\Folders\MyDocuments\CTTV';
 var case2='User\Folders\MyDocuments\FE';
 var case3='User\Folders\MyDocuments\FF';
```

But it always return me null.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z]+\\)+(Documents){1}\\{1}((CT([A-Za-z]){0,2})|(FE)|(FF))$/);
regex.test(case1); //false
```

Might be someone else also faced such issue in Javascript typescript.

Comment: Your regexp expects `\Documents` to be contained in the string, but all your testcases have `\MyDocuments`

Comment: I doubt that your expression works fine as the regular expression is anchored to the start of the test string and searches for a repetition of sequences of letters terminated by a backslash, followed by the literal `Documents`. However, all your test strings contain `MyDocuments` instead, the `My` prevents the pattern to match. As an aside, the repetition operator `{1}` in your regex makes no sense (unless your regex is autogenerated by some code).

Comment: Furthermore, if you literally want a `\ ` contained in a string variable, you have to escape it like `let case1 = 'User\\Folders\\MyDocuments\\CTTV'`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by one of the comments, the test strings are `MyDocuments` but your regex has `Documents`.  If you adjust your regex to this:

`^([a-zA-Z]+\\)+(MyDocuments){1}\\{1}((CT([A-Za-z]){0,2})|(FE)|(FF))$`

It works fine

https://regex101.com/r/xoGaue/1

Answer (score 1):

So the reason why it does not work at the moment is that you are trying to match the string myDocuments to Documents.

To fix your regex I would add a partial match for regex by adding `.*?` this will match any possible characters.

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\\)+(.*?Documents.*?){1}\\{1}((CT([A-Za-z]){0,2})|(FE)|(FF))
```

but I would change your regex all together:

if you do not care about the document folder then I would suggest:

```
^(.+)\\+((CT([A-Za-z]){0,2})|(FE)|(FF))$
```

else you can use:

```
^(.+)\\+(.*?Documents.*?){1}\\((CT([A-Za-z]){0,2})|(FE)|(FF))$
```

see here:

https://regex101.com/r/qd4Fjs/1

Comment: This is not working in JavaScript. although the expression is correct but JavaScript not recognize it.

Comment: can you please edit the question to add the flavour of regex you are using, if I use EMCA it still works?

Comment: The regex probably doesn't work, because the `\ `  in the assigned string variables are not escaped ...

Comment: @derpirscher that is probably it, I didn't notice it. he should raw the string or escape the characters

Answer (score 0):

1. add "My" to "Documents"
2. use String.raw`` to escape backslash

Check it out":
https://playcode.io/918676/

```js
    let 
    case1=String.raw`User\Folders\MyDocuments\CTTV`,
    case2=String.raw`User\Folders\MyDocuments\FE`,
    case3=String.raw`User\Folders\MyDocuments\FF`,
    case4=String.raw`User\Folders\MyDocuments\False`

    let regex = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z]+\\)+(MyDocuments){1}\\{1}((CT([A-Za-z]){0,2})|(FE)|(FF))$/);
    
    console.log(
      regex.test(case1),
      regex.test(case2),
      regex.test(case3),
      regex.test(case4)
    )
```